# Delete only outer vertices from faces in a faces-and-edges-selection selection

Tags: python, edit-mode, vertices

this is a one shell mesh that is not water-tight, in edit mode.

[image: Mesh to edit]

The selection was performed as it follows: Select All; Select Boundary Loop; Select More (3 times); Select Less (3 times).

The objetive is to delete the vertices inside the red loop so that the border of the mesh is smoother. Any idea how to do it?

Comment: Welcome to bse.  Watertight? Consider looking at the [bmesh module](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#module-bmesh.ops)   For mesh above I would search for boundary vertices that are only used in one triangle face and remove them..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting faces works just fine

Script here:

```
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')

bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
bpy.ops.mesh.region_to_loop()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_more()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_less()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_less()
bpy.ops.mesh.select_less()
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type='FACE')

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Comment: Does deleting only the faces leave unwanted edges and verts?

Comment: everything conected to the unwanted verts is removed